# Proving $g(2n)=0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given that $f$ is an odd function periodic with period $2$ and continuous for all $x$ and $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$
then the question is to prove $g(2n)=0$

$g(2n)=n\int_0^2 f(x) dx=n g(2)$ so I have to prove that $g(2)=0$.I could check that $g(x) $ is a even function.Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$g(2)=\int_0^2f(x)\text{d}x=\int_{-2}^0f(x)\text{d}x$$ 
Thus,
$$g(2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^2f(x)\text{d}x+\int_{-2}^0f(x)\text{d}x\right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^2f(x)\text{d}x=0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but I couldn't get your first line we have $g(-x)=\int_0^{-x} f(t) dt$ let $a=-t$ then $da=-dt$ so $g(-x)=\int_0^x (-)f(a)(-)da =g(x)$ so g(x) is even function.hence $g(2)=g(-2)$ can you please explain why lower limit is -2.

Comment: We enforce the substitution $\phi(x)=x+2$, giving $\int_0^2f(x)\text{d}x=\int_{\phi(-2)}^{\phi(0)}f(x)\text{d}x=\int_{-2}^0f(\phi(x))\phi'(x)\text{d}x=\int_{-2}^0f(x+2)\text{d}x=\int_{-2}^0f(x)\text{d}x$ in which the last equality follows by the function being periodic with period $2$.

Using your result that $g(x)$ is even, we might simply note that $g(2)=\int_{-2}^0f(x)\text{d}x$ and $g(2)=g(-2)=\int_0^{-2}f(x)\text{d}x$ simultaneously imply $g(2)=-g(2)$, hence $g(2)=0$.